# listsum(L, S) succeeds iff L is a list of consecutive integers which must start at 1 and S is the sum of that list

Tags: prolog

I'm studying for my upcoming prolog exam and one exercise which I can't figure out needs me to write the following predicate:

listsum(L, S) succeeds iff L is a list of consecutive integers which must start at 1 and S is the sum of that list.

It's important that it's able to generate the list when S is given. numlist/3, is/2 and mathematical operators are allowed to be used.

For example:

```
?- listsum(L, 6).
   L = [1,2,3]
;  false.
?- listsum(L, 7).
false.
?- listsum([2,3], 5).
false.
?- listsum([2,4], 6).
false.
```

How would you write this predicate?

Edit: Thank you so much to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

If it is allowed to use library [clpfd](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-clpfd), another possible solution is as follows:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

listsum(List, Sum) :-
    dif(List, []),
    listsum(Sum, 1, List).

listsum(0, _, []).
listsum(S, X, [X|Xs]) :-
    S #> 0,
    S1 #= S - X,
    X1 #= X + 1,
    listsum(S1, X1, Xs).
```

Some examples:

```
?- listsum(L, S).
L = [1],
S = 1 ;
L = [1, 2],
S = 3 ;
L = [1, 2, 3],
S = 6 ;
L = [1, 2, 3, 4],
S = 10 ;
...

?- listsum([1, 2, 3, 4], S).
S = 10 ;
false.

?- listsum(L, 10).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
false.

?- listsum([1, 2, 3, 4], 10).
true ;
false.

?- listsum([1, 2, 3, 4], 11).
false.
```

Comment: `s/dif(List, [])/List = [_|_]/g` or even better just remove it.

Comment: @false The constraint `dif(List, [])` is needed because the empty list is not a valid answer, according to the problem definition.

Comment: Nevertheless, then say `List = [_|_]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [sum of the first n natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) is `s = n(n+1) / 2` we could use the interesting builtin length/2, and write the relation like

```
listsum_len(L,S) :-
    L=[1|_],
    length(L,N),
    successors(L),
    S is N*(N+1)/2.

successors([_]).
successors([I,J|Ns]) :-
    J is I+1,
    successors([J|Ns]).
```

that covers most of requirements:

```
?- listsum_len([1,2,3],S).
S = 6 ;
false.

?- listsum_len(L,6).
L = [1, 2, 3] .

?- listsum_len(L,S).
L = [1],
S = 1 ;
L = [1, 2],
S = 3 ;
```

The problem of course is that it will not terminate, under some conditions, when *generating* the list by means of length/2.
This will happen on backtracking, for instance because we explicitly require it, or because we cause some of the calls following length/2 to fail, maybe passing a wrong sum.

```
?- listsum_len(L,3).
L = [1, 2] ;
Action (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
?- listsum_len(L,2).
Action (h for help) ? abort
% Execution Aborted
?-
```

It's not easy to solve the problem, but pushing the instantiation check where needed we get a proper solution:

```
listsum([1|L],S) :-
    listsum([1|L],0,S).

listsum([Z],A,S) :-
    S is A+Z.
listsum([I,J|Ns],A,S) :-
    J is I+1,
    B is A+I,
    ( var(S), ! ; B < S ),
    listsum([J|Ns],B,S).
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst inelegant, this will generate, and will also **terminate** sensibly if nonvar arguments are provided:

```
listsum(Lst, Sum) :-
    % Check open list without unintentionally closing it
    (var(Lst) -> true ; \+ \+ (length(Lst, Len), !, numlist(1, Len, Lst))),
    % Reduce unwanted choicepoints
    ((is_list(Lst) ; nonvar(Sum)) -> Once = true ; Once = false),
    listsum_([1|Tail], Tail, Lst, 2, 1, Sum),
    (Once == true -> ! ; true).

% Closing open Lst with empty-list Tail
listsum_(Lst, [], Lst, _Next, Sum, Sum).
listsum_(LU, Tail, Lst, Next, SumU, Sum) :-
    SumU1 is Next + SumU,
    % Terminate if gone past nonvar arguments
    (var(Sum) -> true ; SumU1 =< Sum),
    % Appending to rear of list
    Tail = [Next|Tail1],
    Next1 is Next + 1,
    listsum_(LU, Tail1, Lst, Next1, SumU1, Sum).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- listsum(L, S).
L = [1],
S = 1 ;
L = [1,2],
S = 3 ;
L = [1,2,3],
S = 6 ;
L = [1,2,3,4],
S = 10 ;
L = [1,2,3,4,5],
S = 15 ;

?- listsum(L, 6).
L = [1,2,3].
```

Comment: `listsum([1|_],N), N = 3.`incorrectly fails and
`listsum([2|_],N).` loops

Comment: Thanks for checking - problems fixed, at the cost of added inelegance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given you can use `numlist/3` and mathematical operators and assuming you cannot use `clp(FD)` then you may split the problem in two, one for ground sums and other which will compute sums:

```
listsum(L, S):-
 integer(S),   % ground sum
 End is (-1 + sqrt(1+8*S))/2, % compute ending number
 IEnd is integer(End),
 IEnd =:= End, % checking the sum is an actual valid ending integer
 numlist(1, IEnd, L).
listsum(L, S):-
  var(S),
  numlist2(L, 1, 1, S).
  

numlist2([Cur], Cur, S, S).
numlist2([Cur|L], Cur, CurS, S):-
  Cur1 is Cur + 1,
  CurS1 is CurS + Cur1,
  numlist2(L, Cur1, CurS1, S).
```